# How is the 'secret' used in JWT

Tags: jwt

One of JWT benefits is to avoid managing/storing a session at the server side. However, in JWT the server needs to know the `secret` to corroborate that the incoming message is valid.

My question is: doesn't the server need to store the `secret` somewhere to validate the JWT token coming from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does need to store the secret.  If your server back-end is also issuing the tokens, you'll already have the secret used to sign the tokens available to verify the tokens.  If you have some sort of auth server issuing the tokens, you'll need a shared secret to validate them.